# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1

Tags: c#, .net-core, download, path

I am trying to download a file, using the following settings. The thing is, I am getting an exception saying

`Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1`

For some reason, the `DownloadLocationT` is null and I can't figure out why.

```
if (dl.EndsWith(".las"))
    {
        dl = dl.Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").TrimEnd("las".ToCharArray()) + "zip";
    }
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(dl);
    var newFile = Path.Combine(Startup.appSettings.DownloadLocationT, fi.Name);
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(newFile))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(newFile);
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
         System.IO.File.Copy(dl, newFile);
         return Ok(dl);
```

This is the `appSettings` class

```
public class AppSettings
    {
        public string ArecGISConnString { get; set; }
        public string AllowOrigin { get; set; }
        public string DMSUrl { get; set; }
        public string DownloadLocation { get; set; }
        public string DownloadLocationT { get; set; }
        public string AdminEmailToVerify { get; set; }
        public string PoTreePath { get; set; }
        public string PoTreeOut { get; set; }
        public string MetadataPath { get; set; }
        public string Referer { get; set; }
    }
```

and the actual `appSettings`

```
"AppSettings": {
   //shortened for brevity
    "DownloadLocationT": "C:\\Downloads",
    "AdminEmailToVerify": "info@info.com"
  }
```

I get an exception saying `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path1`
It seems it cannot find the path or folder for `DownloadLocationT`?

Comment: Are the other members of Startup.appSettings null too?

Comment: Not all, 4/12 have a value - @Wibble

Comment: Maybe there's a partly-populated appSettings.Environment.json file overriding parts of your appSettings.json? I've no particular knowledge, but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0 looks helpful.